# Разделить строку, содержащую знак вопроса

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Имеется некая строка, в которой может быть (а может и не быть) знак вопроса '?'. Мне нужно выделить только ту часть строки, которая стоит до вопросительного знака. Я пытаюсь сделать это методом `split()`, т.е. получается что-то типа: `"aa?bb".split("?");`. При этом выскакивает `PatternSyntaxException` с сообщением `Dangling meta character '?' near index 0`.

Можно, конечно, воспользоваться `StringTokenizer` или просто поискать вхождение символа, однако нет ли способа с использованием метода `split()`? Может можно как-то задать знак вопроса как строку, а не мета-символ регулярного выражения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать `split`, нужно два обратных слэша:

```
"aa?bb".split("\\?");
```

Дело в том, что регулярные выражения в Java (в отличие от Perl, JavaScript и т. д.) не поддерживаются на уровне языка. С точки зрения компилятора `"\\?"` — это просто строка, и компилятор заменяет двойной обратный слэш на одинарный, а потом уже обработчик регулярных выражений видит строку `\?` и воспринимает её как экранированный вопросик. Если вы в исходнике напишете `split("\?")`, такое не пропустит компилятор, потому что `\?` — некорректная Escape-последовательность.

Также отмечу, что односимвольные разделители-литералы начиная с Java-7 обрабатываются особой, быстрой веткой в методе `split` без полноценного создания регулярного выражения. Поэтому `"aa?bb".split("\\?");` будет существенно быстрее, чем `Pattern.compile("\\?").split("aa?bb");`, даже если вы прекомпилированный `Pattern` сохраните в константу.

В качестве иллюстрации вот пример сравнения производительности решения с `"\\?"` (plain) и решения с `Pattern.quote()` (quote, тут создаётся полноценный regexp) на JMH:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.openjdk.jmh.infra.Blackhole;
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.*;

@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 1000, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 10, time = 1000, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
@Fork(3)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class SplitTest {
  String s = "aa?bb";

  @Benchmark
  public void quote(Blackhole bh) {
    bh.consume(s.split(Pattern.quote("?")));
  }

  @Benchmark
  public void plain(Blackhole bh) {
    bh.consume(s.split("\\?"));
  }
}
```

Результаты на Oracle JDK 7/8/9:

```
# JMH 1.10.3 (released 40 days ago)
# VM version: JDK 1.7.0_80, VM 24.80-b11
...
Benchmark        Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
SplitTest.plain  avgt   30  0,107 ± 0,001  us/op
SplitTest.quote  avgt   30  0,393 ± 0,003  us/op

# JMH 1.10.3 (released 40 days ago)
# VM version: JDK 1.8.0_40, VM 25.40-b25
...
Benchmark        Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
SplitTest.plain  avgt   30  0,108 ± 0,001  us/op
SplitTest.quote  avgt   30  0,380 ± 0,004  us/op

# JMH 1.10.3 (released 40 days ago)
# VM version: JDK 1.9.0-ea, VM 1.9.0-ea-b72
...
Benchmark        Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
SplitTest.plain  avgt   30  0,108 ± 0,001  us/op
SplitTest.quote  avgt   30  0,375 ± 0,003  us/op
```

Видно, что plain-версия в 3.5 раза быстрее для заданной строки.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не задаваться всё время вопросом, надо ли экранировать в `split` какой-нибудь символ, рекомендуется использовать [`Pattern.quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)):

```
import java.util.regex.*;
// ...
String s = "aa?bb";
String separator = "?";
String results[] = s.split(Pattern.quote(separator));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(results));
```

[Пример приложения](https://ideone.com/veYANY)

Если же для разбиения строк нужно регулярное выражение, `Pattern.quote` пользоваться нельзя.

Comment: Любопытный факт: `s.split(Pattern.quote("?"))` может работать в разы медленнее, чем `s.split("\\?")`.

Comment: @TagirValeev: А Вы не могли бы в таком случае привести пример быстродействия этих решений? Мой вариант просто снимает задачу экранирования вручную - это удобно.

Comment: Да пожалуйста. Вот [гист](https://gist.github.com/amaembo/fab1f18eb39939b6eba9) с JMH-бенчмарком и результатами для Oracle JDK 1.7.0_80, 1.8.0_40 и 1.9.0_ea_b72. В девятке регекс чуть ускоряется, но всё равно в 3.5 раза медленнее. Если у меня разделитель из неизвестного источника, я лучше напишу `Pattern.compile(separator, Pattern.LITERAL).split(s)` (зачем мучать парсер лишний раз?). А если разделитель константный, не вижу ничего плохого в `"\\?"`.

Comment: Да мне то что, я не прочь побаловаться слешами, просто не все понимают, как они работают :) Мне кажется, этот тест надо просто добавить к Вашему ответу.

Comment: Мысль хорошая. Добавил.

Answer (score -2):

Нужно смотреть синтаксис, которым вы оперируете. У меня работает split().

```
String strings[] = S.split("\?");
```

strings[] это ваш массив строк из S

Comment: Вот кстати такую строчку мне почему-то Eclipse не позволяет, пишет мол `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )`

Comment: Без слеша, что происходит с тем, что я написал?

Comment: Выскакивает `PatternSyntaxException` с сообщением `Dangling meta character '?' near index 0.`

Comment: Приведите Ваш код