# Регулярные выражения содержащие ()

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Возник вопрос. Необходимо разобрать строку. В строке содержатся ключевые слова, которые я знаю заранее и мне надо вытащить всё, что между данными словами находится.

Например:

```
Категория Косметика Подкатегория Масла Объем (мл) 25
```

Из этой строки необходимо составить набор записей (для этого использую `HashMap<String, String>`) и получить необходимо набор записей по типу (key, value) (Категория, Косметика), (Подкатегория, Масла), (Объем (мл), 25).

Так как получаю строку с известными `key`, то остается выбрать лишь `value`.

```
pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?" + info.get(k) + " (.*?) " + info.get(k+1));
```

В `info` хранятся ключи. Столкнулся с проблемой нахождения записи подкатегории и объема в строке. Возникает скорее всего из-за `(мл)` у объема, но как это решить не совсем понятно.

Comment: Нужны `Pattern.quote(info.get(k))` и `Pattern.quote(info.get(k+1))`, только еще надо учитывать финальную позицию, `Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(info.get(k)) + "\\s+(.*?)(?:\\s+" + Pattern.quote(info.get(k+1)) + "|\\s*\\z)")`. `Pattern.quote` [используется для экранирования специальных символов регулярок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/445008/182013). `\\s+` находит 1 и более пробельных символов.

Comment: Я так понимаю, вы используете `Matcher.find()`? Покажите свой код.

Comment: Спасибо большое, вопрос был решен Вами, ошибка действительно была в неэкранировании символов.

Comment: Только неэкранирование? А конец строки `|\s*\z`?

Comment: ну на сколько я понял quote сэкранировал спецсимволы и еще окончание строки тоже помогло. спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут необходимо использовать `Pattern.quote` для экранирования любых специальных символов регулярок, а также добавить `|\s*\z` к `info.get(k+1)`, чтобы найти совпадение также в конце строки.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(info.get(k)) + "\\s+(.*?)(?:\\s+" + Pattern.quote(info.get(k+1)) + "|\\s*\\z)");
```

Например, при последней итерации регулярка будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
\QОбъем (мл)\E\s+(.*?)(?:\s+|\s*\z)
```

[См. демо](https://regex101.com/r/hr8BPK/2)

**Подробности**

- `\Q` - далее все символы перестают быть специальными ("режим буквального текста")
- `Объем (мл)` - фраза (подстрока) `Объем (мл)`
- `\E` - конец режима буквального текста
- `\s+` - 1+ пробельных символов
- `(.*?)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: 0 и более символов, отличных от символов перевода строки, как можно меньше
- `(?:` - начало подмаски:

  - `\s+` - 1+ пробельных символов
  - `|` - или
  - `\s*\z` - 0+ пробельных символов и самый конец строки
- `)` - конец подмаски.